# grep output prints only single line in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

How can I get the results from grep to print on their own line in a bash script?

When using grep in the terminal, the output appears how I wish it would appear.

For instance:

```
$ whois x.x.85.72 | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4'
NetRange:       x.x.85.64 - x.x.85.95
NetRange:       x.x.0.0 - x.x.255.255
OrgName:        xxxxx Technologies Inc.
```

When using the same grep command in bash it prints out on one line.

The output of my bash script:

```
$ lookup xx.com
xx.com resolves to: x.x.85.72
NetRange: x.x.85.64 - x.x.85.95 NetRange: x.x.0.0 - x.x.255.255 OrgName:xxxxx Technologies Inc.
```

My bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
VAR1="$1"

IP=`net lookup $VAR1`
echo $VAR1 resolves to: $IP
RANGE=`whois $IP | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4'`
echo $RANGE
```

aside from a solution, can anyone tell me why it does this?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to quote the variable to have the format preserved:

```
echo "$RANGE"
```

instead of

```
echo $RANGE
```

All together:

```
#!/bin/bash <--- be careful, you have an space after ! in your code
VAR1="$1"

IP=$(net lookup $VAR1) #<--- note I use $() rather than ``
echo $VAR1 resolves to: $IP
RANGE=$(whois $IP | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4')
echo "$RANGE"
```

#### Example

Given this:

```
$ date; date
Wed Sep 25 15:18:39 CEST 2013
Wed Sep 25 15:18:39 CEST 2013
```

Let's print its result with and without quotes:

```
$ myvar=$(date; date)
$ echo $myvar
Wed Sep 25 15:18:45 CEST 2013 Wed Sep 25 15:18:45 CEST 2013
$ echo "$myvar"
Wed Sep 25 15:18:45 CEST 2013
Wed Sep 25 15:18:45 CEST 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting is very important in the shell, you need to quote all your variables to preserve the newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1="$1"

IP=$(net lookup "$VAR1")
echo "$VAR1 resolves to: $IP"
RANGE=$(whois "$IP" | egrep 'OrgName|NetRange|inetnum|IPv4')
echo "$RANGE"
```

Read `man bash` under the quoting section. Also using `$()` is much clearer than using backticks and it allows nesting.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quote of the `$RANGE` variable.

You should use:

```
echo "$RANGE"
```

Without the `quote` the newline isn't preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
RANGE=`whois $IP | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4'`
echo $RANGE
```

with

```
whois $IP | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4'
```

or

```
RANGE=`whois $IP | grep 'OrgName\|NetRange\|inetnum\|IPv4'`
echo "$RANGE"
```